# C# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework Core asynchronous ToQueryable comparison

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, asqueryable

I am using `EfRepository<TEntity>` to access data and I have a `DbSet<TEntity>`.
I'm trying to access data asynchronously and I need it is as `Queryable` and I'm currently using this:

```
public virtual async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> AllAsync()
{
    var list = await this.DbSet.ToListAsync();
    return list.AsQueryable();
}
```

Is it actually faster than using the `DbSet` synchronously?

Comment: Just remember that any time you use ToList it means that the enumeration will execute, the database will be called and the results will be stored in memory and the whole idea of IQueryable is to avoid that and only query the database and perform enumeration on demand...

Comment: @DeanKuga Both `IEnumerable<T>` and  `IQueryable<T>`  support lazy loading but the difference is the compiler generates an expression tree for the `IQueryable<T>`.  I agree the OP shouldn't ToList.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it actually faster than using the DbSet synchronously?

Much, much, much slower actually.  That will load all the entities into memory before returning an in-memory IQueryable.

Your additional, second-level repository should return the DbSet directly as an `IQueryable<T>`.  It's up to the calling code to specify the query and execute it either sync or async.

Lots of people have written "generic repository" wrappers for EF.  They all add complexity, and most of them do more harm than good.

Comment: Definitely. The `DbContext` IS a repository. An additional generic repository will be 90% pointless wrapping of DbContext functions and the remaining 10% will be iffy code that causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

Like most things, it depends. If you are running in a console application and your goal is to completely load the list of entities into memory as fast as possible, the synchronous call will be a bit faster. If you are running queries like this in a web application then you should plan on multiples of them happening concurrently.  Threads are a precious resource in a web application. Running a query synchronously will tie up a thread that could be used to handle other web requests while you query is I/O blocking.  So you can maximize time to last byte by making a synchronous call, but you can maximize the overall throughput of the system (and avoid thread starvation) by using the asynchronous call.

In the end, you probably need to measure it.

Comment: Concurrent database requests are a precious resource.  Network throughput capacity is a precious resource.  Web server threads are comparatively cheap.  Having hundreds of threads in a process is no big deal.   A thread is at most 1MB of memory for the stack and some handles. Running hundreds of concurrent queries requires tens of cores.  It's vanishingly rare that using async for database access would materially improve your application throughput, response time, resource consumption, or hosting cost.

Comment: And yet asp.net core 3.1 often suffers from thread starvation and the culprit is always the use of synchronous calls - at least according to David Fowler. I haven't actually counted all the issues in github myself :-)

Comment: A web server framework needs to limit the number of concurrent requests to not overwhelm back-end systems, and to degrade gracefully under excessive load.  As part of this it must set expectations for how applications behave.  ASP.NET Core expects you to use the async methods, as it's an async-oriented system.  Blocking threads frustrates its expectations about resource management.  It isn't inherently more expensive.